# Converting xsd to clojure.data.xml.Element loses data when attribs have colon in name

Tags: xml, mongodb, clojure, xsd

I’m having trouble reading an xsd file.
When it converts it to an #clojure.data.xml.Element, it loses some attributes, such as xmlns:tns – how do I convert it correctly?

Ultimately I want to save xml to a noSQL database (I’m using mongodb with monger as it has good support) and then output back as the same xml later.

Here a sample xsd, but I want to be able to upload any xsd/xslt/xml file:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/PurchaseOrderSchema.xsd" 
           targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/PurchaseOrderSchema.xsd" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <xsd:element name="PurchaseOrder" type="tns:PurchaseOrderType"/>
 <xsd:complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="ShipTo" type="tns:USAddress" maxOccurs="2"/>
   <xsd:element name="BillTo" type="tns:USAddress"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="OrderDate" type="xsd:date"/>
 </xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:complexType name="USAddress">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="name"   type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="city"   type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="state"  type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="zip"    type="xsd:integer"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:NMTOKEN" fixed="US"/>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Here’s a sample of the code I use to read it:

```
(ns example
  (:use compojure.core)
(:require [clojure.data.xml :as xml] ))

 (defn uploadXMLfile
  "Upload xml file"
  [file]
    (let [xmlstr (slurp (:tempfile file))]
      (xml/parse-str xmlstr :supporting-external-entities true 
                            :namespace-aware true 
                            :replacing-entity-references true)))
```

The output I get is:

```
#clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :schema, :attrs {:targetNamespace http://tempuri.
org/PurchaseOrderSchema.xsd, :elementFormDefault qualified}, :content (#clojure.
data.xml.Element{:tag :element, :attrs {:name PurchaseOrder, :type tns:PurchaseO
rderType}, :content ()} #clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :complexType, :attrs {:na
me PurchaseOrderType}, :content (#clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :sequence, :attr
s {}, :content (#clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :element, :attrs {:name ShipTo, :
type tns:USAddress, :maxOccurs 2}, :content ()} #clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :
element, :attrs {:name BillTo, :type tns:USAddress}, :content ()})} #clojure.dat
a.xml.Element{:tag :attribute, :attrs {:name OrderDate, :type xsd:date}, :conten
t ()})} #clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :complexType, :attrs {:name USAddress}, :
content (#clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :sequence, :attrs {}, :content (#clojure
.data.xml.Element{:tag :element, :attrs {:name name, :type xsd:string}, :content
 ()} #clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :element, :attrs {:name street, :type xsd:st
ring}, :content ()} #clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :element, :attrs {:name city,
 :type xsd:string}, :content ()} #clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :element, :attrs
 {:name state, :type xsd:string}, :content ()} #clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :e
lement, :attrs {:name zip, :type xsd:integer}, :content ()})} #clojure.data.xml.
Element{:tag :attribute, :attrs {:name country, :type xsd:NMTOKEN, :fixed US}, :
content ()})})}
```

Comment: `((slurp (:tempfile uploadSourceXML)))` should throw an error. slurp can return a String or nil, neither implements IFn.

Comment: is the function you used to parse the xml missing there? because slurp can't return a `clojure.data.xml.Element`

Comment: I have corrected the missing part, so it shows the xml/parse-str   - Thank you for spotting that.

Comment: the slurp call is still broken `((slurp x))` will always throw an exception for any `x`

Comment: I've corrected the slurp. What I'm concerned about is the missing attributes, such as xmlns:tns

Comment: I wonder if it could be related to this issue? http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/DXML-26

Comment: I've now tried different combinations of xml-input-factory-props but it hasn't affected the outcome.